# Bones point towards ground

Tags: animation, bones

Looking for a way/constraint to point bone towards ground, always. I am trying to build a robot leg with a toe, and when the leg moves up, the toe points down, unfortunately I am not able to find a way to do it other way than manually.

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to utilize more bones and constraints for this
I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but maybe it can be a starting point.

The toe bones have a "Locked To" constraint which are tracking the "track_to" bone, I set up a foot bone which is what you will animate and the "track_to" bone will follow the foot bone along the ground which has "Copy Location" constraint on it. Download the Blend if you want to deconstruct the setup.

[image]

[image: mech leg rig]

Bonus Gif

[image: mech walk cycle]

Comment: Wonderfu, that is exactly what I needed, thank you :)